# RichText Email on Blackberry

Tags: email, blackberry, richtext

We are currently sending our emails as HTML but it is not rendering properly on the blackberry. It add's extra blank lines. I assume that is because of the 
 tag. Anyways when sending them as plain text they render correctly, but now the user wants some of the keywords to be bolded. Would rich text format be viable? Should it render properly in the blackberry and if so what would be the syntax for a new line \n.

Note: The HTML emails render correctly in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had pretty good experiences with html mails on BB 4.5 and up (although not perfect). Try using paragraph tags instead of the new line character.

But you may need to fiddle around a bit with the email format to get it looking great.